# Using c:url in c:set

Tags: jsp, jstl

I need to use some link as argument to `<spring:message />` and use `<c:set/>` for that. To have link relative to contextPath i use `<c:url>`. Why using `<c:url/>` in `<c:set/>` inside  like below doesn't work ?

```
<c:set value='<c:url value="/x"/>' var='doc1'/>
<spring:message code="doc.link" arguments="${doc1}"/> <%-- ${doc1} is empty --%>
```

Simlar using `<a href/>` works good:

```
<c:set value='<a href="/fullurl/x">here</a>' var='doc1'/>
<spring:message code="doc.link" arguments="${doc1}"/>
```

messages.properties:

```
doc.link = Doc is {0}
```

**EDIT**
I need to work exactly something like that:

```
<c:set value='<a href="<c:url value="/x"/>">here</a>' var='doc1'/>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put it in the tag body:

```
<c:set var="doc1"><a href="<c:url value="/x" />">here</a></c:set>
<spring:message code="doc.link" arguments="${doc1}"/>
```

Or if you want XML well-formness:

```
<c:url var="url" value="/x" />
<c:set var="doc1"><a href="${url}">here</a></c:set>
<spring:message code="doc.link" arguments="${doc1}"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

`<c:url>` has an option to set the result to a variable, rather than outputting it. Just set the `var` attribute.

```
<c:url value="..." var="doc1" />
```

Comment: I don't agree. I'm using something like that: `<img src="<c:url value="/r/images/pn.png"/>"/>` without var attribute.

Comment: don't agree with what? It has an _option_ to do that. If you don't use that option, it will output the result to the page. If you use it (specify `var`), it will be stored there instead

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
<c:url var="myURL" value="/x" />
<spring:message code="doc.link" arguments="${myURL}" />
```

Because your message is `doc.link = Doc is {0}` where in the `{0}` appears at the end of the message, you can simply change the message to `doc.link = Doc is` and do as follows:

`<spring:message code="doc.link" /><a href="<c:url value="/x"/>">here</a>`

That will do exactly what you want to do!