# How do I call a JSTL Variable as data attribute?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm trying to set data variable(data-url) for a button, but when I check it out in the inspector, the **data-url** of said button is "0".

Can anyone help me figure out what I've done wrong? This is the code I'm referring to

```
    <c:url var="ajax-url" value="/product/internal" />
    <button data-url="${ajax-url}">
        blabla
    </button>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd start by not using a minus operator in a variable name. Java has naming conventions. Respect them, and everything will be sooooo much simpler.

Comment: ... that was the definition of a noob mistake, i believe. thank you very much. changed it to ajaxUrl and it works now

Comment: Please reference this solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614114/using-curl-in-cset

Comment: @JBNizet agree!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <button data-url="<c:url value = "/product/internal"/>">
        blabla
 </button>
```